# How to Find an object Based on a certain attribute in ArrayList and edit the object

Tags: java, object, arraylist, attributes

Title says it. Is there to Find an object in an `ArrayList` BASED on a certain attribute then EDIT a different attribute of the object.
For instance:

`MyList.Find( Attribute ).edit(something in attribute)`

Comment: Your question is very vague and unclear for me! Please add more information

Comment: Simplified it means
I have an arraylist of objects
I want to find a object with an certain unique attribute that it has
I then want to edit another attribute of that object
can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the list until you find the object with the desired attribute.  Now you have the object.  Use the setter on the object for the other field.

You may want to consider storing your objects in a Map instead of a List.

Comment: why should OP use a map?

Comment: If the objects are in a map with the key being the attribute that gets searched, then the time complexity is O(1) instead of the O(n) that iterating through a list is.

Comment: yes but it's very hard to keep the key snycroniced... if you update the value, the key will be different. so please be careful with that

Answer (score 0):

Not in the native Java classes.

You either need a library that supports this or write it on your own.

I would suggest a simply method that returns the first match:

```
public static CustomObject findFirstByXxx(List<CustomObject> list, Object xxx) {
    for(CustomObject o : list) {
        if(o.getXxx().equals(xxx) {
            return o;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

you can also try to make the attribute you want to search for variable by using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the binarySearch method.

Sample:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(array, Object, new Comparator<Object>() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1.getProperty().equals(o2.getProperty()))
        return 0;

    return -1;
    }
});
```

Comment: The list must be sorted into ascending order